# difference between this two condition

Tags: c#

what is difference in this two condition

```
return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1 ? true : false;

return res =! 0 ? true:false;

return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 ? true : false;
```

what is difference in this three condition when i check the existence of information in the table [mysql]

Comment: Hello 
second one have syntax error.Correct it
return res !=0 ? true:false;

Comment: yeah i am write second by hand not copy so it is my fault.

Answer (score 8):

You are using ternary operator.

1st->`return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1 ? true : false;`

True:-When the output of  `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` is equal to 1.
False:-if its not equal to 1.

2nd->`return res =! 0 ? true:false;` it have syntax error

The correct one is that `return res != 0 ? true:false;` it have syntax error

True:-when res not equal to 0.

False:-if res  equal to  0.

3rd->`return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 ? true : false;`

true:-if value of `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` is greater than 0.

otherwise false.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to specify `? true : false` in any of these.  Just `return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;` (for example) will do the trick.  There will be no difference as far as the database is concerned and any performance difference in the application will be negligable and should be ignored.  What's left is just the basic logical differences between comparing the result as equal to 1, not equal to 0 or greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

All three versions have slightly different logic:

- The first version returns `true` when the value is `1`, otherwise `false`.
- The second version returns `false` when the value is `0`, otherwise `true`.
- The third version returns `true` when the value is positive, otherwise `false`.

If your value can only ever be `0` or `1` then all three of them will be functionally equivalent, but this isn't guaranteed by the code itself since an `Int32` has 2^32 different states.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first and third expressions are similar. But the first returns true only if the result is 1, the third returns true as long as the result isn't zero. So if the sql command returns 2 for example, the result will be different.

Expressions number two, I'm not sure why you want to compare it with the other two.

BTW, the ternary operator ?: is redundant in all three lines. You could just as well write

```
return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;

return res =! 0; 

return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
```